# Sharing documents using dropbox

Tags: dropbox, file-sharing, google-drive

I need to share some documents with some other collaborators and (that's important) I need to know **when** a file was last modified and **who** modified it.

I was wondering if Dropbox could be the solution, I've never used before.
An alternative could be Google Drive, but I don't know if a google account is needed to all users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, dropbox is able to do it, after installing DP (dropbox) simply click on the DP icon on menu bar, right click, and choose: "Launch dropbox website". on the website you can see modified, and if you right click a file you can select "Previous versions" and  see who edited (or deleted in our worst case that happened lately..)

Comment: ofcourse this will be via browser.. so i am not sure they even need to all install dropbox, just have an account and log-in from website

Comment: It will work straight from the website. You don't need the client first.